# Interfacing between text input and the server for purpose of executing a command-line application using that text

Tags: python, node.js, shell, command-line, flask

as a learning exercise I am trying to create a simplified clone of codepad.org, and the first language I want to support is C.

For context: if I was making a simple note-taking web app (simple Evernote, for example), I can see how the architecture is simply that you would need a server running to route requests, so if I have three buttons (new, save, open) if I click 'new' it renders a page that lets you type words, and if I click 'save' the server takes that data and then stores in a database, however all of this is very self-contained and doesn't involve the extra component of opening up a terminal in the box that my app is running from and then creating a file on the box filesystem using the code that a user inserts into the text input form, and then executing the command-line command to compile/interpret the code depending on the language.

How does one do that?

I can see that the steps are as follows:

1. Node.js or Flask server is running
2. I goes to localhost:9000, and a template renders that has a form that I can put code text into
3. I select 'C' from the languages dropdown
4. I write some simple and valid C code
5. I click 'execute'
6. The server routes this POST request and the data to use as the code to execute and somehow instantiates a new terminal session, saving the file to disk and then executing the needed command (gcc temp1.c -o temp1.x)
7. temp1.x is executing, and whatever appears in standard output is piped back through the server to the page and the output renders accordingly.

How do I do 6 and 7? Not looking for step by step instructions, but is there a word or programming concept I should look up to find out how I'd do this? I am thinking of writing the app in Flask or as a Node.js application depending on what is available but I am open to any suggestions. I have searched quite a bit and have not found the words to use appropriately in order to inquire further on how to implement the extra step of interfacing between the server application running on an actual physical server and other tools that the operating system would allow you to use otherwise...

Hope this question makes sense, and I understand that this isn't a specific programming question but I did not know where else to put this other than Stack Overflow.

I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

1. To save the files, you can use the [Flask API](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/). To run the command, you would use [`subprocess.Popen`.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)
2. You would also use `subprocess.Popen` to get the output. Basically, when calling `Popen()`, you would set the argument `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, and then call `subprocess.Popen.communicate()` to get the output. For example:

   ```
   cmd = subprocess.Popen("command to run C code", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
   output = cmd.communicate()[0]
   ```

I highly suggest Flask, you could prototype this application very quickly in it.